# using three composite keys or one primary key

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, composite-primary-key

I have a table that contains 3 composite keys (type: Number). Is it better to add an extra column to use it as a primary key (type: autoNumber) and if so why?

Comment: if you use only on eprimary key it will increase performance. as it have to traverse only one column

Comment: Please provide more specifics. In general, if certain columns need to be unique, you will not be able to remove a key from them just because you added another key. More info can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info).

Comment: @Fred, Are you sure you mean **three** composite keys? Or do you really mean **one** composite key consisting of three attributes?

Answer (score 0):

One column is more efficient.
That way, if it becomes a FK later, there is less key to migrate.